# How can I set different fonts for tabitem header and content of this tabitem?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, tabitem

How can I set different fonts for tabitem header and content of this tabitem??

Comment: Which language/environment/OS/etc are you using?

Comment: I've updated the tags...you may also want to edit your question to make it a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like anything in WPF, there are many ways.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do, here is one "for instance" (I wouldn't suggest using this combination of fonts:) )

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="headerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Papyrus" />
                <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource headerStyle}" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Here is the content" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```